# How can I solve the error "Dataset was not found in location US" in BigQuery?

Tags: error-handling, google-bigquery, location, dataset, bigdata

I'm trying to run some tests with Google BigQuery to calculate data from my Google Spreadsheets. When trying to run the code, I am getting the error: "Dataset was not found in location US".

I have already tried processing the site in "Automatic" or "EU" in the query settings but neither of each has brought any useful results.

The code I used is this one here:

```
SELECT a.Customer AS Customer,
       round(100.00*sum(b.Online_Sales)/sum(a.Sales), 2) AS PctOnlineSales
FROM
    Dataset.Big_Data_Test_1_Sales a
JOIN
    Dataset.Big_Data_Test_1_Online_Sales b
ON a.Customer = b.Customer
--WHERE a.Customer IN ('1002')
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

I expected to multiply the data of two sheets that are schemed in my dataset.

Can you guys help me fix the location issue?

Thanks in advance!
Nes

Comment: Can you try using the format projectId.datasetId.table in your query and advise if this as any impact on the error message

Comment: Could you please send me the code-snippet I shall use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your project Id before the dataset so BigQuery can locate it. This is an example based on your code

````
SELECT a.Customer AS Customer,
       round(100.00*sum(b.Online_Sales)/sum(a.Sales), 2) AS PctOnlineSales
FROM
 ProjectId.Dataset.Big_Data_Test_1_Sales a
JOIN ProjectId.Dataset.Big_Data_Test_1_Online_Sales b
ON a.Customer = b.Customer
--WHERE a.Customer IN ('1002')
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1```
````

Answer (score 0):

FROM
Dataset.Big_Data_Test_1_Sales a

project_id was missing from the above syntax, thats why it returns "Dataset not found in location US".